Playwright with .NET Integration, getting the following error while running browser
The following is my code for running the test, it is a simple function app with the following test, but I am getting error of timeout with some headless issues. The function app is deployed to Azure and I am getting the error logs in App Insights.
CODE:
    namespace AvailabilityTestTimerTrigger.Function
{
    public class CustomAvailabilityTest
    {
        private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;
        private static readonly string[] Locations = new[]
        {
            "australiaeast",    
            "brazilsouth",      
            "centralus",        
            "eastasia",       
            "eastus",           
            "francesouth",      
            "francecentral",    
            "japaneast",        
            "northeurope",      
            "northcentralus",   
            "southcentralus",   
            "southeastasia",    
            "ukwest",           
            "westeurope",       
            "westus",           
            "uksouth"
        };

        public CustomAvailabilityTest(TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration)
        {
            _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
        }

        [FunctionName("CustomAvailabilityTest")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, ExecutionContext executionContext)
        {
            var tasks = new Task[Locations.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Locations.Length; i++)
            {
                var location = Locations[i];
                tasks[i] = RunTestForLocationAsync(location, executionContext.FunctionName, log);
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }

        private async Task RunTestForLocationAsync(string location, string testName, ILogger log)
        {
            var availability = new AvailabilityTelemetry
            {
                Name = testName,
                RunLocation = location,
                Success = false,
            };

            availability.Context.Operation.ParentId = Activity.Current?.SpanId.ToString();
            availability.Context.Operation.Id = Activity.Current?.RootId;
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            try
            {
                using (var activity = new Activity("AvailabilityContext"))
                {
                    activity.Start();
                    availability.Id = Activity.Current?.SpanId.ToString();

                    // Run the Playwright test
                    var testSuccess = await RunPlaywrightTestAsync(log);
                    log.LogInformation($"Playwright test for location - {location}, resulted value - {testSuccess}");
                    availability.Success = testSuccess;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                availability.Message = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                stopwatch.Stop();
                availability.Duration = stopwatch.Elapsed;
                availability.Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
                _telemetryClient.TrackAvailability(availability);
                _telemetryClient.Flush();
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> RunPlaywrightTestAsync(ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
                await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
                {
                    Headless = true,
                    Timeout = 60000, // Set launch timeout to 60 seconds
                    Args = new[] { "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--no-sandbox" }
                });

                var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

                // Set a default timeout for all actions on this page
                page.SetDefaultTimeout(60000); // 60 seconds

                await page.GotoAsync("https://www.google.com/");
                
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError($"Playwright test encountered an error: {ex.Message}");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

ERROR LOGS:
Playwright test encountered an error: Timeout 60000ms exceeded.
Call log:
  - <launching> /home/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1129/chrome-linux/chrome --disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-back-forward-cache --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-component-update --no-default-browser-check --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync,Translate,HttpsUpgrades,PaintHolding,PlzDedicatedWorker --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --disable-search-engine-choice-screen --unsafely-disable-devtools-self-xss-warnings --headless=old --hide-scrollbars --mute-audio --blink-settings=primaryHoverType=2,availableHoverTypes=2,primaryPointerType=4,availablePointerTypes=4 --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-setuid-sandbox --no-sandbox --user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-XXXXXXsDbx8k --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window
  - <launched> pid=1762
  - [pid=1762][err] Old Headless mode will be removed from the Chrome binary soon. Please use the new Headless mode (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/chromium/new-headless) or the chrome-headless-shell which is a standalone implementation of the old Headless mode (https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-headless-shell).
  - [pid=1762][err]

I was expecting it to run successfully. I checked Playwright Docs, the new headless mode is not supported, but in the error it is suggesting to use the new headless mode.

Can you share your complete code in the question?

Sure, I have Updated the Post with complete code. I am using Playwright to make custom availability test on Azure Application Insights.
